# Do not scale element border

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations, keyframe

I'm using keyframe animation to make increasing transparent 1px-circle. But div border is increasing with width and height. Is there any way to make circle with not-increasing border?

```js
$(document).on({
    click: function (e) {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.className = 'clickEffect';
        d.style.width = '1px';
        d.style.height = '1px';
        d.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
        d.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        d.addEventListener('animationend', (() => {
            d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
        }).bind(this));
    }
});
```

```css
div.clickEffect {
    position: fixed;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    animation: clickEffect 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes clickEffect {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        opacity: 0.5;
        transform: scale(20);
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not really, at least not with transform, you need to animate width and height `@keyframes clickEffect { 0% { opacity: 1; width: 1px; height: 1px} 100% { opacity: 0.5; width: 20px; height: 20px}}`. Its a little worse performace wise, but well, it works.

Comment: Performance is important for me. Is there any way to do such effect with scale only??

Comment: No, there is no way to achieve that with scale only.

Answer (score 0):

Animate width & height instead of scale.

```js
$(document).on({
  click: function(e) {
    var d = document.createElement('div');
    d.className = 'clickEffect';
    d.style.width = '1px';
    d.style.height = '1px';
    d.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
    d.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
    document.body.appendChild(d);
    d.addEventListener('animationend', (() => {
      d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
    }).bind(this));
  }
});
```

```css
div.clickEffect {
  position: fixed;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  z-index: 99999;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  animation: clickEffect 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes clickEffect {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0.5;
    //transform: scale(20);
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your solution has problems with performance - width and height animation works more slowly than scale

Answer (score 0):

You must animate the height and width instead of the scale.

And to keep it centered, you must translate X and Y

So the code would look like this:

```js
$(document).on({
    click: function (e) {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.className = 'clickEffect';
        d.style.width = '1px';
        d.style.height = '1px';
        d.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
        d.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        d.addEventListener('animationend', (() => {
            d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
        }).bind(this));
    }
});
```

```css
div.clickEffect {
    position: fixed;
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    animation: clickEffect 0.5s ease-out;
}

@keyframes clickEffect {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
  opacity: 0.5;
  transform: translateX(-20px) translateY(-20px);
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your solution has problems with performance - width and height animation works more slowly than scale

Comment: Yes, but using scale(), you cant scale heigth and width whitout scale the border size.

Answer (score -1):

Here is another idea that rely on translation and perspective to achieve a scale effect keeping the same border

```js
$(document).on({
    click: function (e) {
        var d = document.createElement('div');
        d.className = 'clickEffect';
        d.style.top = `${e.clientY}px`;
        d.style.left = `${e.clientX}px`;
        document.body.appendChild(d);
        d.addEventListener('animationend', (() => {
            d.parentElement.removeChild(d);
        }).bind(this));
    }
});
```

```css
div.clickEffect {
    position: fixed;
    border-radius: 50%;
    z-index: 99999;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin:-10px 0 0 -10px;
    border:1px solid #000;
    transform:perspective(200px) translateZ(-250px);
    animation: clickEffect 1s ease-out;
}

@keyframes clickEffect {
    0% {opacity: 1;}
    100% {opacity: 0.5; 
    transform:perspective(200px) translateZ(90px)}
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```